# Docker com React, fazer um refresh das atualizações sem precisar subir o container de novo

Tags: node.js, react, docker

Criei uma aplicao em react e resolvi rodar ela com docker localmente, apenas para desenvolvimento

No Dockerfile ficou assim:

```
FROM node:8
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

No docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3'

services:
 node8-app:
  build: .
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  volumes:
   - ./:/usr/src/app
```

Funcionou, mas quando eu faco alguma alteração, e salvo, eu preciso matar o container, e subir de novo para ver o que mudou.

Tem alguma forma de fazer isso, sem precisar matar o container?

Answer (score 1):

No `Dockerfile` crie o seguinte código.

```
FROM node:8

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json .
COPY yarn.lock .
RUN yarn

COPY . ./code

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start.dev" ]
```

No seu `Compose` utilize

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app/code
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules # Remove this if you have pure JS dependencies
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

Por fim, mude o caminho de seu `package.json` utilizando

```
{
  "main": "code/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index",
    "start.dev": "nodemon"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.14.12"
  }
}
```

Sempre que alterar seu `index.js` utilize `docker-compose up --build` isso faz um refresh em seu index sem a necessidade de restartar ou recriar o container.

Referencias, pode verificar nesse [link](https://gist.github.com/ksmithut/e126f7ddb40b760487a17e8b569a77b5)

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma que acho um pouco mais "limpa" você pode criar os seguintes arquivos:

**Dockerfile-dev**

```
FROM node:8

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /

VOLUME /app
EXPOSE 3000

CMD yarn; yarn start
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  react-docker-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    user: ${CURRENT_UID}
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
```

Para executar, rode o comando `CURRENT_UID=$(id -u):$(id -g) docker-compose up -d --build`

A variável `CURRENT_UID` é para que seu usuário seja o mesmo da execução do container e não bloquear a pasta `node_modules`.

Obs.: Eu uso o script shell abaixo para auxiliar o desenvolvimento:

**dev.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export STACK_NAME="dev"
export CURRENT_UID=$(id -u):$(id -g)
case "$1" in
    start)
        echo "Starting ${STACK_NAME} stack"
        docker-compose -p ${STACK_NAME} up -d --remove-orphans --build
        ;;
    stop)
        echo "Stopping ${STACK_NAME} stack"
        docker-compose -p ${STACK_NAME} stop
        ;;
    restart)
        echo "Restarting ${STACK_NAME} stack"
        docker-compose -p ${STACK_NAME} restart
        ;;
    clean)
        echo "Cleaning ${STACK_NAME} stack"
        docker-compose -p ${STACK_NAME} down -v
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Accepted commands: start, stop, restart or clean"
        ;;
esac
```

Fonte de exemplo nesse repositório [git](https://github.com/arkanjoms/react-docker-app).